# How to do these effects in jQuery? (Fading hover and sliding icon)

Tags: jquery

I have been deseperately looking for the scripts which do similar effect on links like here: http://applemaybe.com/

see on top menu, clicking the link, hover state does not come immediately but faded, also the icon slides up in a nice way. I need the script which makes the exact same effect please.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just look at their source code to see how it works rather than wait and hope till someone will write this code for you...

Comment: You can always have a look at the source code. Also you might be interested in finding out what CSS sprites are.

Comment: They are simply using a [sprite](http://applemaybe.com/wp-content/themes/applemaybe/images/menu.sprite.png) for `background-image` and animating the `background-position` property when toggling the `.active` class.

Comment: The fading effect can be easily done with css3 (transitions). Just saying.

Comment: It is done without javascript at all. Just css-transition of the background-images. `-moz-transition-property: color, background;` is doing all the magic together with to different background-positions of the sprite for the active and the normal link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually using CSS3 transitions. If you accept that it doesn't work in all browsers since it is an eye-candy effect, I would suggest you to do the same. Doing it in JavaScript will probably not yield as good result and might also have poor performance results.

Doing it in CSS3 is easy and fast. On the mentioned site they just have this CSS3 class:

```
a, .link {
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    ...
}
```

However it will only work in Firefox in this case. You should take care that CSS3 is not finished yet so it might evolve in the future.

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) for documentation on CSS3 transitions.